# I'm in a pub with only port 80 and I need to SSH into something

Tags: proxy, port-forwarding

Any public proxy ideas that I can use right away over port 80?

I would presume this is a common problem.
Would be nice to know if there are any sites sites or tools for solving it.

Comment: Phone someone with admin privileges and have him change the SSH port to 80.

Comment: Must free wireless setups use a transparent proxy which will throw away non-http connections. You might have better look with port 443 though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's your own server, you can install [shellinabox](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/). This would allow you to setup a Web based AJAX terminal emulator where you use your browser as you with with any terminal.

Comment: This is what I did, after I used a questionable 3rd party service called ConsoleFish, with terrible timeouts, to download and set it up (and later I changed my password, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing public that I know of, but if you have your own server somewhere or could rent a cheap VPS (the smallest of them would do) you could instal something like http://www.nocrew.org/software/httptunnel.html and use that when you are in the pub.

Though I recommend putting the laptop down and enjoying your drink instead!

Comment: Thanks :)
Would love to just enjoy a drink but there is a Python conference here in the UK and I need to setup some Unconferencing software, and no one else is here yet so it's all good. :)

Answer (score 0):

To allow remote shell access to host from web browser (require html+css+javascript):

http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm

Comment: This requires more ports than port 80 already working to setup as the question says but it is close to a second part of a solution, but it's not an answer in itself.